# Replace empty fields in tab separated file with "0"

Tags: awk, sed

Say I have a data file with rows like `a^I^I^I^I^I^I^Ib^Ic`, which is separated by `^I` (means a tab).

Now, I want to change the empty value of each column into 0, so the result should be like: `a^I0^I0^I0^I0^I0^I0^Ib^Ic`.

How can I achieve it with only one sed command?

Comment: So your real data doesn't have `^|`, it actually has tab characters?

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to do using a tool with support for look-ahead:

```
perl -pe 's/\t(?=\t)/\t0/g' file
```

This puts a "0" in between any pair of tab characters. The look-ahead is useful as it matches the second tab without consuming it, so it can be used in the next match.

Here's a way you could do it using awk:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) sub(/^$/, 0, $i) } 1' file
```

This loops through all the fields, substituting all empty ones with a 0.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed ':a;s/\t\(\t\|$\)/\t0\1/;ta' file
```

Replace all `\t` followed by `\t` or end of line with `\t0`.

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -v RS='\t' -v ORS='\t' '$0==""{$0=0}1'
```

or with BEGIN block

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\t"} $0==""{$0=0}1'
```

Comment: That would add a line containing just a tab with no terminating newline to the end of the output and so make the result not a POSIX text file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{while(gsub(/\t\t/,"\t0\t"));} 1' file
a       0       0       0       0       0       0       b       c
```